# What type of wire should I use to connect my buttons/sensors from 3 feet away?

Tags: wire

So I've got a little prototype using some buttons and [pressure sensors](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9376) plugged right into the breadboard. My next step is that I actually put the buttons and sensors where I want them, but they're going to be about 3 feet away from the breadboard. Should I just use standard 22 AWG hookup wire cut to length?

Comment: Define "pressure sensor".

Comment: Yeah, more specifically a force sensitive resistor: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a length of wire to each device will increase their resistance, but generally no more than 20 ohms or so depending on the gauge of the wire.

For a button using the internal pullup the overall resistance must be less than \${{20\text{k}\Omega⋅0.3}\over{0.7}} \approx 8.5\text{k}\Omega\$ or so in order to reliably register a low. Adding 6 feet of wire (3 feet towards, 3 feet back) is unlikely to cause the resistance to increase that much.

The pressure sensor is a variable resistance device however, and as such may require recalibration when connected to the wires if the actual value is used rather than just using it for presence sensing.

Also note that longer wires pick up RF more easily, so you should consider twisting the pairs connected to the device (or using twisted-pair wire in the first place) and using ferrite beads/toroids and/or common-mode chokes to suppress the disturbance caused by the RF, especially in an electrically noisy environment..

Comment: I have two buttons and two sensors. Would using the twisted pairs of a Cat5 cable make sense?

Comment: It could, assuming the devices aren't spaced out too far from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think twisting the wires AND using a choke makes any difference. The point about twisting the wires is that the RF noise is induced into both wires and you then use a differential input receiving amplifier to remove the common mode noise (but you need to transmit the signals as a balanced pair to begin with, which means using a differential line driver).

A choke creates inductance whose impedance increases with frequency, thereby attentuating any high frequency noise on the line (wires). So a choke should work whatever you do with the wires, twisted or not.

Comment: This looks like a comment for Ignacio's answer. The best scenario might be a shielded cable with the shield's drain wire (poking out of the cable) is grounded at the PCB. Whether or not the wires are twisted, the shield will absorb the RF and other interference and redirect them to ground rather than the possible sensitive analog measurement or sensitive digital comparator.